# can we update docker default configure?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, configure

require:

I need change the "**LogConfig**" type to **syslog**.

I known this can be working:

> docker run --log-driver=syslog

but, I start container by k8s in cluster now.How to configure the LogConfig? or how to change it`s default to syslog?

---

Thanks @Jan Garaj and @molivier

**this is my docker version**

```
[root@ip-hostname ~]# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.2-el7.centos
 API version:  1.20
 Package Version: docker-1.8.2-10.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a01dc02/1.8.2
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.2-el7.centos
 API version:  1.20
 Package Version:
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a01dc02/1.8.2
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
After=network.target
Wants=docker-storage-setup.service
```

**This configure:**

```
[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-network
Environment=GOTRACEBACK=crash
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon $OPTIONS='--log-driver=syslog' \
          $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS \
          $ADD_REGISTRY \
          $BLOCK_REGISTRY \
          $INSECURE_REGISTRY
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity
MountFlags=slave
TimeoutStartSec=1min
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then:

> systemctl daemon-reload
>
> systemctl restart docker

**Look like not working...**

> docker inspect 7fa2e28203b1

```
 "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ]
```

please help...

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the docker default configuration in **/etc/default/docker** ([daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/)):

```
DOCKER_OPTS='
-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376
-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
--storage-driver aufs
.../...
--log-driver=syslog
'
```

Have a look to [configuring docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/configuring/).

Edit: As mentionned by Jan Garaj ([issue 9889](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9889)) the /etc/default/docker file is only used on systems using "upstart" and "SysVInit", not on systems using systemd ([see systemd config](http://docs.master.dockerproject.org/engine/admin/systemd/)).